# Rearranging Text Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some code from Mailchimp that I am trying to use to place an archive of newsletters on my site but the formatting is not the best. It is showing as a plain list with the Date - Title Link of the emails. I would like for it to list the Title first (floated left) and the Date second (floated right) and remove the "-". I know I can do most of the formatting in CSS but guessing I need to use JavaScript to rearrange the text. I am new to JavaScript and would like to learn how to do this.

This is the code from Mailchimp

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--.display_archive {font-family: helvetica,verdana; font-size: 18px;}
.campaign {line-height: 125%; margin: 5px;} 
//-->
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="//itleaderboard.us18.list-manage.com/generate-js/?u=3c0abed3fa8e00bd96d5481fd&fid=8258&show=10" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

[Here is an image of the rendered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrDtc.jpg)

Comment: Please include an example of the rendered output. We can't help you rearrange HTML (in CSS or JavaScript) if we don't know what HTML is there...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oops, sorry about that! I updated the post to include a link to a screenshot of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML tree of the list has a wrapper div with a class name campaign for each row in the list. In this div there's a text node with the date and an `a` element link with the title.
So, first we can access the text node with `childNodes[0]` of the wrapper campaign element and replace the " - " with an empty string. Then we can move the `a` element to the beginning of the campaign element with `insertAdjacentElement` with `afterbegin` as the first argument.

I put this code in a function and added an onload attribute to the script that creates the list. This way the code function runs after the list is present.

(Note that I placed the function in a `<script>` tag in the html, instead of the JavaScript section of the snippet, be cause when I did the latter I would get an error that the function was not defined.)

For the styling you want, we can add `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to the parent element.

```css
.campaign {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function arrangeText() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.campaign').forEach(elem => {
      elem.childNodes[0].textContent = elem.childNodes[0].textContent.replace(' - ', '');
      elem.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', elem.lastElementChild);
    })
  }
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="//itleaderboard.us18.list-manage.com/generate-js/?u=3c0abed3fa8e00bd96d5481fd&fid=8258&show=10" type="text/javascript" onload="arrangeText()">
```

For further styling your list, you may want to wrap the date text in a `<span>` element for better control

**Update**

Here is a snippet where I added the code for wrapping the date in a span element.

```css
.campaign {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function arrangeText() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.campaign').forEach(elem => {
      const textNode = elem.childNodes[0];
      textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(' - ', '');
      const newSpan = document.createElement('span');
      newSpan.classList.add('campaign-date');
      elem.append(newSpan);
      newSpan.append(textNode);
    })
  }
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="//itleaderboard.us18.list-manage.com/generate-js/?u=3c0abed3fa8e00bd96d5481fd&fid=8258&show=10" type="text/javascript" onload="arrangeText()">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had guessed at logic behind this based on other posts I had read but wasn't able to recreate it successfully on my own.

Comment: Quick question, I'm working on wrapping the date text in a <span> element. Would I use something like this? 

document.getElementById("idname").textContent="Your value";

Comment: No. You need to create the element with `document.createElement('span')` and then append the new element to the campaign element then append the text node to the new element. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: @TracyKistler I added a snippet with wrapping the date in a span to the answer.

Comment: Got it! This was very helpful not only in achieving my goal but in understanding javascript better! Thank you!